# sparklyr ml_kmeans Field "features" does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib, sparklyr

AWS EC2 Spark / Hadoop cluster.

The following baisc K-Means sparklyr code worked with Spark 2.0.1

```
  kmeans_model <- iris_tbl %>%
  select(Petal_Width, Petal_Length) %>%
  ml_kmeans(centers = 3)
```

I've upgraded to **Spark 2.1.1**, and I get this error

```
    Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not exist.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:264)
 ...
io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
```

I've made some tests with the code

```
kmeans_model <- iris_tbl %>%
  select(Petal_Width, Petal_Length) %>%
  ml_kmeans(k = 3, features = c("Petal_Length", "Petal_Width"))
```

or

```
kmeans_model <- iris_tbl %>%
  dplyr::select(Petal_Width, Petal_Length) %>%
  ml_kmeans(centers = 3, features = c("Petal_Length", "Petal_Width"))
```

But still get the same error.

Comment: I'd expect the `features` argument to work for backwards compatibility. You can track the issue at https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/1150. We are encouraging the `formula` interface as @user9019279 points out below though, since it can support interactions for supervised learning algorithms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code wouldn't work in Spark 2.0, the same way it cannot work in more recent versions. The application of this code is incorrect independent of Spark version. By default `ml_kmeans` (and other `ml_*` functions), expect `Vector` type column named `features`. `features` can used to override the name and should be:

> a length-one character vector

The only way you could make it work, without using `ft_vector_assembler`, is to provide `formula`:

```
kmeans_model <- iris_tbl %>% 
  ml_kmeans(formula= ~ Petal_Width + Petal_Length, k = 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To override the features column name one would actually specify `features_col` (corresponds to Scala `featuresCol`). `features` should still be respected for backwards compatibility and I'm pushing a fix for that.

Comment: I accept the answer, but still the code worked in Spark 2.0 as I stated  at the beginning of my post